# Where could I see uninstallation directives for a plugin?

Tags: uninstallation

Where could I see uninstallation directives for a plugin?

I have a plugin named "Wordfence" I want to remove. I need to remove it manually due to what might be a bug in the plugin. How Could I see what files and tables (or data inside tables) the uninstallation process deletes?

I mean, generally in Wordpress, under what php file, plugins usually have their installation directives?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

WordPress uses two methods to unistall plugin:

1. uninstall.php file in plugin's root folder. If file exists, it is executed and second method is not used.
2. A function registered by plugin via register_uninstall_hook(). You should search it in plugin's php files.